# Java contextual sax / stax parsing

Tags: java, dom, sax, xml-parsing, stax

I would like to extract all text elements which appear *directly* as a **child node** to the **root node**. I've had a glance at java standard sax fascilities using [`DefaultHandler`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html); but it doesn't seem like it's *path* aware.

The problem is getting `first-level only` nodes, not [extracting only text-nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293841/how-to-get-element-only-elements-with-values-stax).

Is there any non-DOM oriented approach to do this? (Note, the node names are not known in advance)

**[EDIT]**

### Sample input

```
<root>
   <a>text1</a>
   <b>text2</b>
   <c>text3</c>
   <nested>
       <d>not_text4</d>
       ...
   <nested>
   ...
</root>
```

### Sample output

```
Map<String, String> map := {
    {a, text1}
    {b, text2}
    {c, text3}
}
```

---

Currently solved as a DOM oriented workaround. Although there exist libraries which offers a subset of xpath expressions for SAX / STAX.

Comment: If you add some example input xml and expected result we can better help you.

Comment: @Don Roby, Certainly. Question updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAX and StAX indeed aren't path aware by nature as they're event oriented.  While it's certainly possible to implement a handler that tracks parsing level, you're probably better off with [XPath](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html).

A somewhat more complex tactic might be to write an XSLT transform that retains only the elements you're after and then process the result using SAX or Stax.

Comment: I'm afraid you are right. Good news is there might be a way for [streamig xpath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996103/streaming-xpath-evaluation)

Comment: @Johan - yes, that might work.  Also see my update for another possibility that wouldn't require loading the whole doc.

Answer (score 1):

This will be a little overhead, but you get a powerful tool to work with xml. Try [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/).

Comment: Thanks, although I need to efficiently extract a `List<String>` of all *first-level* elements in an xml document rather than converting them to java objects.